# Webview can't render Virtual DOM and shows blank in SPA using Vue-CLI

Tags: java, android, vue.js, android-webview, vue-cli-4

I'm a web developer and don't know android programming.

my problem showed itself when I decided to lunch my single page app that created by vue cli 4 for mobile devices

actually I used this repository for build a webview for it:

https://github.com/slymax/webview

but I don't know that why does it show blank page? (I just know my webview can render DOM but can't render virtual DOM of my application.
because I tried to run my app with any browser and it worked but in webview I couldn't see my results)

any way...
where is my problem? If you need to check some config files like vue.config.js or something like that in my vue cli directory, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded my problem! It's about my plugins in vue-cli like vue-hammerjs

It's not support webview platforms and after disable all of them in main.js, everything was going right.

Comment: Are you saying that WebView does not support Vue plugins? ie: Vuex?